# Interaction between sample_weight and min_samples_split in decision tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

In sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier, if we define both `sample_weight` and `min_samples_split`, does the sample weight impact the min_samples_split. For example, if min_sample_split = 20 and the weight of data points in samples are all 2, then 10 data points satisfy the `min_sample_split` condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, see [the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/80598905e517759b4696c74ecc35c6e2eb508cff/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L224); `min_samples_split` does not take into consideration sample weights.  Compare to `min_samples_leaf` and its weighted cousin `min_weight_fraction_leaf` ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/80598905e517759b4696c74ecc35c6e2eb508cff/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L391-L401)).

Your example suggests an easy experiment to check:

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = [0, 0, 1]

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
tree.fit(X, y)
print(len(tree.tree_.feature))  # number of nodes
# 3

tree.set_params(min_samples_split=10)
tree.fit(X, y)
print(len(tree.tree_.feature))
# 1

tree.set_params(min_samples_split=10)
tree.fit(X, y, sample_weight=[20, 20, 20])
print(len(tree.tree_.feature))
# 1; the sample weights don't count to make 
#    each sample "large" enough for min_samples_split
```